# How to save stream in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream

How can a stream be saved in Node.js other than memory? Tried using Redis, but it only works with strings, dates and buffers. An example of the current code:

```js
const Docker = require('dockerode');

const streams = {};

exports.startTerminal = async (id, socket) => {
  const container = docker.getContainer(id);

  try {
    const inspectData = await container.inspect();
    const isRunning = inspectData.State.Running;
    if (!isRunning) await container.start();

    const stream = await container.attach({ stream: true, stdin: true, stdout: true, stderr: true });

    socket.emit('terminal-started');

    stream.write('reset\n');
    stream.on('data', chunk => {
      socket.emit('terminal-output', chunk.toString('utf8'));
    });

    streams[id] = stream;
  } catch(err) {}
};

exports.terminalInput = (data, id, socket) => {
  const stream = streams[id];
  stream.write(data);
};
```

In this example, we receive user input from the client through sockets and write it to the terminal inside the docker container.

It turns out that when the server is rebooted, all saved streams are lost.

Comment: save to file is not an option?

Comment: No, I need stream as object (abstract interface).